# date filter type is not working in yadcf plugin

Tags: jquery, datatable, yadcf

i have column which display date in it. i am using datatable for display tables.
i have render date column using datatable's `column Render` function and use `yadcf` column filter plugin for filter data. it display datepicker in filter element but not filter data after selecting date from it.

```
$(table_id).dataTable({
        aaData: $.parseJSON(records), 
"aoColumnDefs": [{
                "bSortable": false,
                "aTargets": [1], // <-- gets last column and turns off sorting
                "mData": null,
                "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
                    var cdate = row.date;
                    return cdate.replace(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/, "$3-$2-$1");
}}]
}).yadcf([{column_number: 1, filter_type: "date"}]);
```

Comment: please provide a jsbin / jsfiddle with your sample so I can debug it...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0ztkz9ey/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [latest yadcf version](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/55621125/yadcf/war14/resources/js/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js) and also since you are using the `-` as date sepaartor you need to feed yadcf with the `date_format:  'dd-mm-yy'`

Updated code:

```
.yadcf([{column_number: 1, 
         filter_type: "date", 
         date_format:  'dd-mm-yy'
}]);
```

Here is a [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ztkz9ey/9/) (not sure if you meant to use `dd-mm-yy` or `mm-dd-yy`)

Comment: i am using it with bootstrap 3. after selecting a date it will not close datepicker and not filter data

Comment: currently yadcf support jquery date picker only , for start you better switch to the https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker  and if you want yadcf to support it you should open a new issue on yadcf github page